# why ac current flows in dc motor?

Tags: dc-motor

I know that commutator is used in dc motors to convert dc to ac and vice-versa. But I don't understand why we need to convert the dc into ac in armature conductors of a dc motor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A vanilla commutator doesn't change DC into AC, it connects and disconnects the DC supply from the rotor windings - as the armature is rotating - at just the right time to make and break a  magnetic field which will interact with the fixed stator magnets in a way which will generate the torque necessary to rotate the armature continuously.

Comment: @Vibhu: The commutator flips the magnetic polarity by switching between windings, but it doesn't affect the electricity itself.